# MS Access VBA export XML hierarchy

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database crdatabase that contains below tables:

```
releases
fields:
    name (datatype: string)
    release_status (datatype: string)
    year (datatype: string)

changerequests
fields:
    id (datatype: autonumber)
    description (datatype: string)
    release (datatype: string)
    cr_status (datatype: string)
    affectedcpid (datatype: string, multi-valued, delimited by comma)

affectedcomponents
fields:
    id (datatype: autonumber)
    name (datatype: string)
```

Relationships:
change requests are linked to releases table via release <-> name field.
change requests are linked to affectedcomponents table via affectedcpid <-> id field

I would like to export XML in hierarchy:

```
<crdatabase>
<release>
    <name>release1</name>
    <year>2016</year>
    <status>active</status>
    <changerequest>
        <id>1</id>
        <description>change1</description>
        <cr_status>open</cr_status>
        <affectedcomponent>comp1</affectedcomponent>
        <affectedcomponent>comp2</affectedcomponent>
        <affectedcomponent>comp3</affectedcomponent>
    </changerequest>
    <changerequest>
        <id>3</id>
        <description>change3</description>
        <cr_status>working</cr_status>
        <affectedcomponent>comp5</affectedcomponent>
   </changerequest>
</release>
<release>
    <name>release2</name>
    <year>2015</year>
    <status>nonactive</status>
    <changerequest>
        <id>2</id>
        <description>change2</description>
        <cr_status>closed</cr_status>
        <affectedcomponent>comp1</affectedcomponent>
        <affectedcomponent>comp2</affectedcomponent>
    </changerequest>
</release>
.....
</crdatabase>
```

I tried using AdditionalData in vba as below:

```
Public Sub exportToXML(pFileNAme As String)
    Dim objOrderInfo As AdditionalData
    Set objOrderInfo = Application.CreateAdditionalData
    objOrderInfo.Add("releases")
    objOrderInfo.Add ("changerequests").Add ("affectedcpid")
    objOrderInfo.Add ("affectedcomponents")

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:="releases", _
                      DataTarget:=pFileNAme, _
                      AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo, WhereCondition:="Parameter='test'"
End Sub
```

It doesn't work as expected as it doesn't export in hierarchy nor export the search queries.

Here is what it actually exports:

```
<crdatabase>
<releases>
    <name>release1</name>
    <year>2016</year>
    <release_status>active</release_status>
</releases>
<releases>
    <name>release2</name>
    <year>2015</year>
    <release_status>nonactive</release_status>
</releases>
...
<changerequests>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>change1</description>
    <release>2016</release>
    <cr_status>open</cr_status>
    <affectedcomponent>1,2,3</affectedcomponent>
</changerequests>
<changerequests>
    <id>3</id>
    <description>change3</description>
    <release>2015</release>
    <cr_status>working</cr_status>
    <affectedcomponent>5</affectedcomponent>
</changerequests>
...
</crdatabase>
```

Any ideas? DOM or print (please give example codes) are all acceptable as long as it can be handled in vba. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: What is the field type of [changerequests].[affectedcpid]? Is it a multi-value Lookup field? Also, what do you mean when you say that it "doesn't ... export the search queries"? What "search queries"?

Comment: How does it export? Please post what it currently results to compare with desired results?

Comment: Edited question to show the datatype and what it actually exports.

Comment: Remove `objOrderInfo.Add("releases")` as `releases` is the main table of export. Also, consider a redesign of multivalue field to a many-to-many `affectedcpid` table as your XML attempts to change concatenated data (comma-delimited) to multiple children. As a personal rule, I never use multi-value ID fields as related table links becomes a challenge if otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the release and redesign the affectedcpid in the table, but the problem still remains.